# Change attributes from defs elements for different use elements

Tags: python, svg

I have a SVG with 2 circles. In fact, they use just a single "def" called s1. How can I change attributes from just one circle (use). For example I want to set a different class to the element s1 when using by an specific "use" element.

```
<svg viewBox = "0 0 1000 1000" version = "1.1">
    <defs>
    <!-- A circle of radius 200 -->
    <circle id = "s1" cx = "200" cy = "200" r = "200" fill = "yellow" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "3"/>
</defs>
<use x = "100" y = "100" xlink:href = " #s1 "/>
<use x = "100" y = "650" xlink:href = " #s1 "/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. Changing the defs changes all things they refer to.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change element's specific atributes (cx,cy,r), but you can change all atributes on this  [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=SVG/Attribute#ConditionalProccessing) using `<set ... >`.
For example "opacity". Here is how to change it for your circles (hint: if you open this svg with opera or chrome, put cursor over third circle):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" version="1.1" height="1000px" width="1000px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

<g>
    <rect y="0" width="1000" fill="blue" x="0" height="1000" />

    <defs>
        <circle id = "s1" cx = "200" cy = "200" r = "200" fill = "yellow" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "3"/>
    </defs>

    <use id = "one" x = "100" y = "100" xlink:href = "#s1"/>
    <use id = "two" x = "100" y = "500" xlink:href = "#s1"/>
    <use id = "three" x = "500" y = "100" xlink:href = "#s1">
        <set attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.7"  begin="mouseover" end="mouseout"/>
    </use>

    <set xlink:href="#two" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.2"  begin="three.mouseover" end="three.mouseout"/>
    <set xlink:href="#one" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.4"/>

</g>
</svg>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it solves your problem/question, otherwise feel free to ask if you need more info.